# Chrome Extension: Passing a Message to the Content Script

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

This question has had a massive edit on Monday May 12, 2014

I've figured out how to send a message to the content script with a very basic set up, however when I try adding a few things like an event listener or a window, things stop working...

The manifest.json file stays the same through all of the different versions of the code:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "Message Test",
    "version" : "1.0",

    "browser_action": { 
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
        }
    ]    
}
```

The popup.html file stays relatively the same through all of the different versions:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="message.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <button type="button" id="Popup Window">Popup Window</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The content-script.js file stays relatively the same:

```
var Mymessage;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.greeting == "Can you hear me?"){
        Mymessage = message.theMessage;
    }
    else{
        sendResponse({});
    }
    alert(Mymessage);
});
```

It's this last file that keeps having problems...
message.js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var myWindow;
    function startFunction() {
        myWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "myWindow", "width=500,height=500");

        function MyMessage (){
          chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            var tab = tabs[0];
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
              greeting: "Can you hear me?",
              theMessage: "Chrome Extension Message"
            }, function(response){});
          }
        window.setTimeout(MyMessage , 3000);
    }
    var Process = document.getElementById('Popup Window');
    Process.addEventListener('click', startFunction);
});
```

If I remove the function **MyMessage** and **window.setTimeout(MyMessage, 3000);** the popup button successfully opens a new window.  If I remove the rest of the file except for the code from within the MyMessage function, whenever I'm on a random page and click its extension icon, the alert in the content-script.js file will go off.  I'm trying to change it so the message wont be sent until the user clicks a button in the popup.html and only after the popup created a new window.

Comment: message.js executes before the button exists.

Comment: @Teepeemm  Why would you say that?  The window.js file executes and it's added before message.js

Comment: window.js wraps everything up into an onload listener.  Nothing happens until everything is ready.  message.js executes immediately,  when nothing is ready.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the popup, like I mentioned at the end of my answer?

Comment: I have deleted my answer to this question, and I urge you to delete this question altogether. Stack Overflow expects questions that have **one concrete problem** in them, and is intended to be a useful answer for anyone else stumbling upon the same problem. Your code had lots of unrelated problems, and your question boils down to "this doesn't work, why?" with little debug effort demonstrated. Normally, this should be closed with a reason "too broad".

Comment: Myself and others still tried to help, but this devolved into finding avoidable errors and you arguing "shouldn't be a problem" or "worked for me before" when potential issues were pointed out. Answer comments are not for prolonged back-and-forth where we try to convince you. **Now, your "massive edit" made all existing answers irrelevant.** This makes it go against the purpose of Stack Overflow: not to help you specifically, but leave a "fossil record" of an answer to a problem.

Comment: I recommend you to do the following: 1) Delete this question; it has little value for this site and we cannot help you further while sticking to the format acceptable here. 2) Debug your problems yourself. Most of your problems could have been solved with basic debugging, as described in detail [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging). See also [Dev Tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: 3) After you've completed your own research into problems, break them down to one at a time, construct a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), consider the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and then return here and [ask again](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You are registering 2 click event listeners against a button, one in message.js file and other in window.js

secondly, You have not used permissions in your manifest file,

```
 "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
```

Make a single event listener in a file and send message from it to content script. Hope the below code helps You...

**popup.js**

```
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(
            function(tab){
                console.log(tab);
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "doSomething");     
            }
        );
```

If you want to send message to tab you are browsing use following code's tab.id, it gives correct tab id

```
chrome.tabs.query({"status":"complete","windowId":chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT,"active":true}, function(tabs){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(tabs[0]));
         console.log(tabs[0].id); 
    });
```

**contentscript.js:**

```
var Message;

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "Can you hear me?"){
          Message = theMessagePassed;
          sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
          alert(Message);
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with registering two click events to the same button?  I was under the impression you could register as many events as you wanted with addEventListener...

Here is what I tried that didn't work, is this what you were referring to?

http://pastebin.com/wA1TKz9f

I also tired it with the window.open going before the message passing:

http://pastebin.com/n9CpaNBG

I also updated the manifest.json to include the permissions addendum.

Comment: It is my understanding according to your code that when you will click the button...both of this events will invoke and they will run in parallel..causing problems..

Comment: Good point, though when I tried putting them in the same file, it didn't work...  Have you ever sent a message to a content script?  I just need to figure that out and then I'll work on the other stuff... this shouldn't be too hard really...

Comment: I've just done an edit of my question so it's more relevant to what is going on, could you take a look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help: you could use the background script as an intermediate step.

Send a message from the content script (without specifying any sender), then grab that message with a big switch-case or if-else-if tree inside the single onMessage listener of the background script, broadcast from there and grab that broadcast* in the … wherever you want to message to in the first place.

EDIT:

* I may have confused this with Opera or Firefox, but one of those browsers not only had that feature but the *restriction* that you can only broadcast-to-all from the background script, not pinpoint the receiver. But apparently, [there is a way](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/wxQkpcXxwJ0/mcB_mxFPr_oJ) to create your own broadcast method.

In response to your question:

You can create an anonymous object with any number of attributes (with static values or variables), as seen in the following example.

While those can only be sent as strings (or they're stored as strings? Can't remember), you can still convert booleans, numbers and arrays (probably also JSONs) into strings, and reconvert them on the receiver's end.

contentScript.js

```
 // instantiation
var
  name = 'george',
  age = 21,
  friends = [ 'tim', 'steve' ];

 // convert
age = String(age);
friends = friends.join();

 // messaging
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  method: 'setPerson',
  type: 'person',
  name: name,
  age: age,
  friends: friends
}, function(response){

  if (response) {
    console.log( 'response value: '+ response.value );
  }
  else {
    console.log( 'it did not work.' );
  }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  var
    response = null,
    temp = null,
    s = '';

  if (  request  &&  (request.method === 'setPerson')  ) {

    s += 'name: '+ request.name +'\n';
    s += 'type: '+ request.type +'\n';

    temp = isNaN( request.age ) ? request.age : parseInt( request.age, 10 );
    s += 'age: '+ temp +' — '+ typeof temp +'\n';

    temp = (request.friends === null) ? [null] : request.friends.split(',');
    s += 'friends: '+ temp +' — '+ temp.length +'\n';

    alert(s);

    response = 'it worked.';
  }

  sendResponse({value: response});
});
```

<strike>(You need to have a background.html page in order to see those background console logs.)</strike>

EDIT²: Forget the background console. Let's just use alerts, ffs.

Comment: I haven't used message passing too extensively, if I send a message from the content-script to some other part of the extension, could the response hold a whole set of values or does it need to be a message signalling the message was received like the "goodbye"?  I only need to send the values at one time, I don't need a dialog just yet.

Comment: You're still sending the values from the content script to the background page instead of the background page sending values to the content script, which is what I need.  Chrome Message Passing isn't the same in both directions...  I'm trying to do a simple-one time request https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging and the example they gave isn't working...

Comment: I see. I've always used bi-directional messaging, so I could make use of the sender parameter. Your approach is indeed a little challenge. Have you checked out [this link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/wxQkpcXxwJ0/mcB_mxFPr_oJ) where Boris suggests to use  `chrome.windows.getAll`?

Comment: I have looked at that, I'm not sure what that would look like, this really shouldn't be that hard, it worked before but now its not...

Comment: I've just done an edit of my question so it's more relevant to what is going on, could you take a look at it again?